# PressKey on Form does work because of buttons Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following problem.
I have a school project on visual studio 2013 and i want to open the Menu Form by pressing any key on the keyboard. I have the following code so far.

```
public partial class START : Form
    {
        public START()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(START_KeyPress);
        }
        void START_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
        {
        Meniu form2 = new Meniu();
        form2.Show();
        this.Hide();
        }
```

The problem is this doesn t work when i have some buttons on the Form as well.I think it s has to be something with the form focus, but i m not sure.
If anyone could help me, I'd be very gratefull.

Comment: Use KeyDown instead, set the form's KeyPreview property to True.

Comment: That was the problem. The KeyPreview property was set to false. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey @RaulBosoanca, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

The code works.
You just have to activate the The KeyPreview property.

Comment: Click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.